# itoa implementation returning incomplete string

Tags: c

ok, so im trying to get my itoa_base.c to return a string and im creating a string *str in another function and sending a reference pointer to that string to my function that does the conversion, but when i try to print it to check it, i only get the last character of the string instead of the full string and i cannot figure out why. Also, itoa_base does exactly what itoa does but with the option to convert the base.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void    ft_itoa_base_sneaky(int value, int base, char *str)
{
    char *ref = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    if (value < base)
    {
         *str = ref[value];
         printf("%s", str);
         str++;
    }
    else if (value >= base)
    {
        printf("%d\n", value);
        ft_itoa_base_sneaky(value / base, base, str);
        ft_itoa_base_sneaky(value % base, base, str);
    }
}

char    *ft_itoa_base(int value, int base)
{
    char *str;
    char *tmp;

    str = malloc(sizeof(char) * 32);
    tmp = str;

    ft_itoa_base_sneaky(value, base, tmp);
    printf("\n%s", tmp);
    return (str);
}

int main (int ac, char **av)
{
    char *str;

    if (ac == 3)
        str = ft_itoa_base(atoi(av[1]), atoi(av[2]));
    printf("\n");
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: What is `str++;` supposed to be doing?

Comment: `str++` is incrementing the reference pointer forward to accommodate the next value to be added.

Comment: Starting in `main`, if `ac != 3` you throw yourself into a pit of despair by printing from the *unitialised pointer* `str`. Work from the ground up: check every step.

Comment: No! Don't change the code on-the-fly. Let people read valid comments. This is not a dynamic code revision site. Rolled back.

Comment: sorry, its my first time using stackoverflow.

Comment: and could you elaborate a little bit on what you mean?

Comment: Who are you addressing the comment to? Two people have commented - please reply to @ChristianGibbons or similarly to WeatherVane (sorry only one `@` user address is allowed in a comment).

Comment: `str` is locally-scoped pointing to somewhere else.  When you increment it, only the local `str` you have is incremented, but you promptly return from the function after incrementing it, which means that line is effectively useless.

Comment: @WeatherVane i was addressing you

Comment: What behavior is expected when `value < 0`?

Comment: You may find [this `my_itoa_base()`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/132592/29485) useful.

Comment: @chux the code was incomplete at the time i wasnt worrying about that case yet, sooo a pit of despair

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `ft_itoa_base_sneaky`, you increment `str` but then you don't do anything with it afterward.  And since `str` is a local variable, changes to it won't be reflected in the calling function.  The double recursion also isn't necessary.

Since the recursion handles the digits in reverse order, have the base case (which handles the most significant digit) write index 0 to the string and change the function to return the index it handles.  Then in the recursive case write to the returned index plus 1.

```
int ft_itoa_base_sneaky(int value, int base, char *str)
{
    char *ref = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    if (value < 0) {
        int idx = ft_itoa_base_sneaky((-value) / base, base, str) + 1;
        str[idx] = '-';
        return idx;
    } else if (value < base) {
        str[0] = ref[value];
        return 0;
    } else {
        int idx = ft_itoa_base_sneaky(value / base, base, str) + 1;
        str[idx] = ref[value%base];
        return idx;
    }
}
```

Then the calling function can use this index to set the null terminator:

```
int idx = ft_itoa_base_sneaky(value, base, tmp) + 1;
tmp[idx] = 0;
```

Comment: Works OK as long as `value >= 0` else its UB.  I suppose the calling function can test.

Comment: @chux Added a case to account for negatives.  It still doesn't account for `INT_MIN`, however.

Comment: Yes `INT_MIN` is pesky.  For me, I use `value <= 0` in the [recursive helper function](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/132592/29485).